# HighChart Gantt Chart Data overlap issue if the handler is close together

Tags: highcharts, highcharts-gantt

In the Highchart Gantt chart if we reduce the navigation handler width too much it will overlap the data when scrolling. Is there a way to set the minimum handler width to eliminate the issue?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `xAxis.minRange` property to limit the minimum width of the range.

```js
xAxis: {
    minRange: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30 // 1 month
}
```

**Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9vyw3mhx/ 
**API**: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.minRange